# Create Column for Date Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

apologies for the noob python question.

I'm running the following code:

```
######import the relevant packages######

#used for urls parsing
import urllib.parse

#used for making http calls on the internet
import requests

#allows for loading and unloading json data
import json 

#used for date and time functions
import datetime 
import time

#used for data processing 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#expand column width
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 1000)

#data time parameters
date = datetime.date
today = datetime.date.today()
end_date_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start_date_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
start_date = today - start_date_delta
end_date = today - end_date_delta

#test end point
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=AAPL&apikey=demo"

#initial json response
response = requests.get(url)

#data returned by api in string format
json = json.loads(response.text) 

#convert json to dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json['Time Series (Daily)'], orient= 'index').sort_index(axis=1)
data.rename(columns={'1. open': 'open', '2. high': 'high', '3. low': 'low', '4. close': 'close', '5. volume': 'volume'}, inplace = True)

#extract close price and volume
data = data[['close']]

print(data)
```

the output looks like this:

```
                   close
    2020-06-12  338.8000
    2020-06-11  335.9000
    2020-06-10  352.8400
    2020-06-09  343.9900
    2020-06-08  333.4600
```

but i want to flatten the file and add a "date" column so I can do date filtering. I want it to look this:

```
    date          close
2020-06-12  338.8000
2020-06-11  335.9000
2020-06-10  352.8400
2020-06-09  343.9900
2020-06-08  333.4600
```

How do I fix? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date is the `index`, so you may want to do `reset_index`

```
data = data.rename_axis('date').reset_index()
```